# how to deal with quotes in a string when passing that string to the command line

Tags: c#, string, command-line

I can't get my head around quotes.

EG, I have a string for an mp3 with quotes:

```
string ARTIST = "John \"The Man\" Doe"
```

I then want to pass this to a command line WITH the escape sequences. I therefore need my string to look like (I think):

```
ARTIST = "John \\\"The Man\\\" Doe"
```

So it looks like, for every time I have an (actual) `"` in my string, I need `\"`.

I have tried using:

```
ARTIST.Replace("\"","\\\"")
```

But this has not worked. What is the correct way to handle quotes at the command line in my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are doing:

```
ARTIST = ARTIST.Replace("\"","\\\"");
```

Instead of just:

```
ARTIST.Replace("\"","\\\"");
```

Is this the case already?

Answer (score 0):

The windows command line doesn't use \ as an escape for a quote, it uses a redundant quote,

so you want to send `"John ""The Man"" Doe"` which you get in C# by escaping each quote

```
string ARTIST = "John \"\"The Man\"\" Doe"
```

Comment: thanks but the string I retrieve from elsewhere, it already comes as `"John \"The Man\" Doe"` (for example)

Comment: it is being fed into the LAME.exe mp3 encoder and the \ escape character works when i tried manually

Comment: The method of escaping quotes is application specific, but most applications use the \ escape characters (C#'s `Main(string[])` uses \ escape characters, for example).

Comment: yes, but most command line parsers _dont_ because \ is the path separator in windows.

Comment: If you read the docs on how `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs` works, you'll see it has some provisions on how this works. So only \" is treated as an escape, but C:\ is not. (IIRC this is the same for MS VC++.) See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea does seem to be correct, but did you also add the surrounding quotes, i.e.,

```
"\"" + ARTIST.Replace("\"", "\\\"") + "\""
```

Also, note that you'll need three backslashes rather than two to escape `\"`; the compiler would complain if you didn't.